# Flutter - fill list with firebase collection

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a list of messages that I want to fill on init with a firebase collection.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_first_flutter_app/chatmessage.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:logging/logging.dart';
final Logger log = new Logger('ChatScreen');

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new ChatScreenState();
}

class ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _chatController = new TextEditingController();
  final List<ChatMessage> _messages = <ChatMessage>[];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Flexible(
          child: ListView.builder(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            reverse: true,
            itemBuilder: (_, int index) => _messages[index],
            itemCount: _messages.length,
          ),
        ),
        new Divider(
          height: 1.0,
        ),
        new Container(decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
        ),
          child: _chatEnvironment(),)
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to do this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('chats')
        .document('ROOM_1')
        .collection("messages")
        .getDocuments()
        .then((snap) {
      return new Column(
         ....
```

but I need to return a Widget, while this attempt returns a `Future`.

How I can fill the `_messages` array with data coming from my firestore collection on the initialization of my chat screen page?

Comment: You can try to use [StreamBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to display all messages in a ListView from the firestore collection, then maybe you'll love the StreamBuilder widget. You can do something like this:

```
return new Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    new Flexible(
      child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('chats').document('ROOM_1').collection('messages').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          if (!snapshot.hasData){
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text("No data")
              )
            );
          }

          return ListView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            reverse: true,
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
              return ChatMessage(text: snapshot.data.documents[index]["messageField"]); //I just assumed that your ChatMessage class takes a parameter message text
            }
          );        
        }
      )

    ),
    new Divider(
      height: 1.0,
    ),

    ...
```

Note that in this example, I didn't use the `_messages` variable.

Comment: How do you get a specific field (aka `content`) from the `snapshot.data.documents[index]` variable? I tried to use the `data()` or `get()` methods of a document to get the field, but those methods didn't work. I am not sure how to debug this - Is there any way to debug the `snapshot.data.documents[index]`?

Comment: You can try printing the value of `snapshot.data.documents[index]` inside the itemBuilder of ListView.

Comment: That's what I get:  `Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'` by doing: `print(snapshot.data.documents[index].toString());`

Comment: Did you try `print(snapshot.data.documents[index][yourField]);`? Where `yourField` is one of your field in that document.

Comment: @JeromeEscalante If I would like to print the value of a specific key in the collection, let's say only messages with the value of "blablablaaa" from the `messageField` key. Do I do `snapshot.data.documents[index]["blablablaaa"]`? Cheers, Karen