# StreamBuilder with Firestore loading vs no data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This feels a bit like a bug to me but I'm not sure. I have simple Firestore query in a Flutter app that I'm running through a Stream Builder. Looks something like this -

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').where('toNumber', isEqualTo: '123').snapshots();
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
    return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  } else {
    if (snapshot.data.length == 0) {
      return Center(child: Text("No Data"));
    } else {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
            _buildList(
                context, snapshot.data[index]),
      );
    }   
  }
)
```

The problem is that if the query returns no results then all you see in a continuous progress indicator. I would of thought `hasData` would return true but it seems this is not the case. I've also tried using ConnectionState but this always returns `.waiting`.

In this situation how would you differentiate between a query which is loading and a query which doesn't return any results?

Comment: Sharing the query will help us help you.

Comment: Ah yes that would be helpful! Updated.

Comment: I know you put the query in the stream property just for the sake of example, but you might want to show it separately or other users will say that is part of the problem, because it would be re-opening the Stream every time the widget was rebuilt.

Comment: I see what you're saying but even though the above is simplified it still displays the same symptoms. In reality though it's not too different as I'm just returning the same stream from a bloc.

Comment: @ChrisEdgington hi, did you find why this is happening. I am having the same situation. when there is no data the connectionState is always "waiting". As soon as I add a document to the firestore, connectionState is changing to "active"

Comment: I suggest you see this example:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53977191/flutter-fill-list-with-firebase-collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53977191/flutter-fill-list-with-firebase-collection)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
if (!snapshot.hasData) {
 if (snapshot.data.length == 0) {
      return Center(child: Text("No Data"));
    }
   else{ 
    return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: With this I get `The getter 'length' was called on null.`

Comment: Can u try if(snapshot != null){if(snapshot.data.length == 0){.....

Answer (score 0):

Here is my build method. I've just tested it, it's working.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: firestore
            .collection('todos')
            .where('state', isEqualTo: false)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          print(snapshot.connectionState);
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return snapshot.data.documents.isNotEmpty
              ? ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                    return Text(snapshot.data.documents[index].data["title"]);
                  })
              : Text('No Data');
        });
}
```

This prints:

```
I/flutter ( 6216): ConnectionState.waiting
I/flutter ( 6216): ConnectionState.active
```

Comment: Thanks @easeccy but this doesn't deal with the 'No Data' situation.

Comment: Updated the answer.